# Is there a way to allow continuous scrolling in Adobe Reader?

Tags: scrolling, adobe-reader

I am having to read through a MASSIVE (1000+ page) PDF specification in Adobe Reader.  It has always bugged me that if you scroll to the edge of a page, the Reader automatically jumps to the top of the next page.

Is there a way to cut this functionality off so that as I'm scrolling, the bottom of the current page has a minimal space, and the next page continually scrolls into view, rather to jump in and take over the full display area?

I know that Microsoft Word can behave this way.  Is there a setting in Adobe Reader 10, or higher, that I can change that will allow continuous document scrolling?

Comment: In new Adobe Reader click on [Menu] -> View -> Page Display -> Enable Scrolling

Answer (score 139, accepted):

**For Adobe Reader X, XI:**

**To make continuous scrolling the default behavior:**

*Edit » Preferences » Accessibility » Always use Page Layout Style*. Check *Single Page Continuous*.

**To only do this for the current session:**

Go to *View » Page Display* and check the option *Enable Scrolling* (this is only a **one-time fix** and will be reset the next time you open Adobe).

---

**For Adobe Reader 9:**

Go to *View » Page Display* and check the option *Single Page Continuous*.

[image: They see me scrollin', they hatin']

Comment: This setting is initialized from the PDF file. You'll rapidly become accustomed to doing this every time you open the offending document... At least in Reader X there is a toolbar button whose tool tip reads "Fit to window width and enable scrolling" located to the right of center of the tool bar items that does what it says on the tin.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for epub and mobi

Comment: Absolutely incredible that this isn't the default configuration...

Comment: Works on Reader XI also.  I was about ready to lynch whoever did the manual I was reading.

Comment: This solution led me to another solution for a problem annoying me -- the default zoom. Turn off the zoom override here, and use the one under Page Display. Much appreciated for the quality answer!! **Note: both of these are still relevant answers in 2017 for Acrobat Reader**

Comment: The default behaviour fix worked for me, but I had to open & close the file for it to take effect. I suppose it would have worked right away if I made both suggested changes, however.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question and answer more than once. I search for it every time I set up Acrobat on a new computer.

Answer (score 78):

Everything they said was fine but when you close and open Adobe Reader again, it goes back to single page viewing and that's annoying.

It's better to **make it the default** by doing this:

*Edit » Preferences » Accessibility » Always use Page Layout Style*. Check *Single Page Continuous*.

This helped me much more than having to keep switching it.

Comment: This is the real gem amongst these answers. Other methods of setting the default view, such as suggested by @sblair don't work.

Comment: love it. Make it default is my fav choice.

Answer (score 28):

For continous scrolling on full screen perform the following steps:

- Go Fullscreen: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>
- Enable AutoScroll: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
- Disable AutoScroll: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

Now you can scroll with the normal arrow keys.

Comment: This is only the solution that solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: I was actually looking exactly for autoscroll in fullscreen, thanks for noting this...

Comment: Still works as of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 15/2015.  Still entirely unobvious :)

Comment: Perfect! Impossible to guess!

Comment: I would call this a bug or exploit and it works for me in Reader XI but only while full screen is active. Instead I found that using the `Touch mode` solves this whole issue for me. Using "scroll mode" and "touch mode" at the same time prevents navigation from jumping at the end of a page. But the toolbar will look different...

Comment: amazing !!! worked perfectly !!!

Comment: Perfect! How did you guess this?

Comment: I can confirm, still works for Adobe Reader DC 2021

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable scrolling. In Adobe Reader X, there might be a button for this on the toolbar. If it's not there, you can choose to show the button by right clicking on the toolbar and selecting `Enable Scrolling` from the `Page Display` option.

You can make this the default view from `Edit` > `Preferences...` > `Page Display` > `Page Layout`. Set this to `Single Page Continuous`.

Answer (score 3):

In Adobe Reader open the **View** menu and in the **Page Display** sub-menu choose **Single Page Continuous**.

Alternatively, you can use you keyboard by pressing the below keys in the displayed order:

<kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

1. *View » Page Display » Enable Scrolling*
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> for full screen. This will change the cursor to the "hand" and the keyboard arrows will now scroll partial pages.
3. <kbd>Esc</kbd> – This gets out of full screen mode.  The "hand" cursor and partial page scroll is still available.
4. <kbd>Esc</kbd> – This changes the cursor to the "I" bar and resumes the default scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

**For version 2021**

`View` -> `Page Display` -> `Enable Scrolling`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to get rid of this annoying mode is choose another reader. I use pdf-xchange which let me chose single-page continuous mode, and un-check "respect to original view mode", so all PDF file opened in continuous mode.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make the scrolling choice permanent is from the Edit/Accessibility option. Edit/Preferences is not working. Can someone in Adobe fix this ?

Comment: I'm curious. Isn't this the same answer as [Lillys](http://superuser.com/a/391201/50173)? Correct me if I'm wrong